# Effective and simple way to get the necessary reputation to upvote good answers?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, meta

I'm tired of lurking. Every question I can think of, I've been able to answer with diligent enough searching. I want to thank good answers, upvote good responses, and offer valuable feedback. Any questions I can think of, I've been able to answer with sufficient searching.

Ironically, except this one. :)

Comment: You can provide answers to increase your points.

Comment: I'd love to! Finding a questions that I *can* answer (that hasn't already been answered) has proven pretty tough. I'm looking for some pro tips contribute something valuable.

Comment: Provide good edits; there are plenty of spelling mistake ridden questions with terrible grammer to edit into shape and they're +2 a-piece (make sure the edits are substantial though)

Comment: you might like my answer to http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/178800/as-a-new-user-how-do-i-gain-reputation-participate-in-so-if-all-my-questions-ha

Comment: [Suggest edits.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/76251/how-do-suggested-edits-work)

Comment: You haven't lurked nearly enough, apparently.

Comment: Thank you Robert Harvey, that is just what I needed.