# How does a new user participate on meta SE?

Tags: discussion, meta, new-users, community

As a new user who joined after lurking for about a month, I'm finding it difficult to actually participate. Is there anything a new user can do here, or is it better to participate on other sites first before joining Meta?

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/178800/as-a-new-user-how-do-i-gain-reputation-participate-in-so-if-all-my-questions-ha

Comment: relevant: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/44188/how-do-i-participate-in-meta-and-not-die-trying

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/274518/a-way-for-new-users-to-ask-about-their-post-specifically

Comment: If you lurked for the past month I must say you lurked during an a-typical 6 to 8 weeks ...

Comment: It's mostly this situation that makes me want to participate, honestly. Although, I do recognize that I might be better off just lurking on meta and participating elsewhere if that's all I'm here for.

Comment: I agree that this could be a dupe. But the details might matter: If you're new to the network, then what is your *goal* of "participating" on meta specifically? It's not meant to be dismissive, but if you had been a long-time contributor and were p!ssed off by the recent events, then you could change your user name to "Sisyphus" and try to change things. Only participating in order to make clear that you have *some* opinion about *some* things that are discussed here *could* still be valuable, depending on how relevant this is for the network specifically.

Comment: See Help (?), [Our Model](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/whats-meta). Sometimes there's [good times and humor](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/19478/282094), and other times [not so much](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/328160/282094). Lurking is free, fly not too low nor too high good [Icarus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Icarus).

Comment: @Cyare if you post something and unfortunately it is not so well received, you might want to see [Common reasons why your meta post may be negatively received](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/333476/common-reasons-why-your-meta-post-may-be-negatively-received) too.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Meta SE is for asking and answering questions about:

> - Stack Exchange
> - Promotions & Advertising Support,
> - feature requests, or bug reports for the core Stack Exchange engine that powers all Stack     Exchange websites

Basically, issues that affect the entire network of Stack Exchange sites.

A new user like yourself might have questions that you want to ask about any of this, and in that case, you are absolutely welcome to participate. You may even be able to answer questions here, but, normally<sup>1</sup>, many questions involve some sort of expertise with the SE system and how it's run.

Either way though, you are welcome to try to contribute where you can and are comfortable doing so.

What I did, and what I'd recommend other users do as well, is start by contributing and lurking on the local Meta site(s) of the SE site(s) you frequent. There you'll get a more intimate understanding of how certain sites are run and, generally, a quieter and more forgiving environment in which to learn the ropes. For one thing, child metas don't have reputation.

---

<sup>1 - This last month has been *highly* atypical.</sup>

Answer (score 8):

The answer is probably somewhere in the middle: Combine participation here and elsewhere. MSE contains a wealth of information about how SE sites, as a system, work. A good example and starting point for this is the [frequently asked questions post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/7931/369802). Also, see all the links people are dropping you in comments underneath your question ;)

Then again, without participating on any site, this knowledge is going to be mostly useless. There's a few things a 'new user' can do. [Rubiksmoose](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/337617/369802) pointed them out while I was writing this. If you've been lurking around the network for a long time, or on this site, you might've picked up sufficient knowledge to do those. There are also things like the winter bash contests that don't really need experience on other sites.

But if you really participate on sites, you can use the knowledge you find here, and discover for yourself where things are lacking, and participate here a bit better by sharing those experiences.

There's also a bit of 'system' that suggests it's useful to participate on sites before joining meta: You usually need a [certain amount of reputation points](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/participate-in-meta) before you can participate on site-specific meta sites. This site is one big meta site for all network sites and thus doesn't require this, but like I said it's useful to have some participation somewhere to draw conclusions from.